# linux kernel .config file variable and its corresponding source code

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, static-analysis

I understand how to recompile a kernel for myself. Firstly, I run `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig` to generate a `.config` file. And I also understand the variables in .config file are like switches to control what will be included in the kernel  and what will not.

And recently i am intertested in how the variables in .config file affect the process of kernel building. More specifically, I want to know which part of the linux source code is "switched " by the specific config variable, and my job now is to extract the specific code.

For example, I want to know  how "CONFIG_GCC_VERSION" variable affect the kernel build process, and which part code it will switch on or switch off.

Thx.

Comment: Search the source code for things like `#if CONFIG_GCC_VERSION`